# How to Debug a Laravel Project in Netbeans or Eclipse Using Breakpoints (not var_dump())?

Tags: php, eclipse, laravel, debugging, netbeans

Well for some of you this question might not make sense but I have some difficulties in debugging a laravel Project in Netbeanse.

This question is in two parts:

**First Part**

Netbeanse and Eclipse both provide very good debugging tools like breakpoints, watching variables' values, stack trace etc. I can use these tools with PHP Core projects quite easily but what if I want to debug a model or controller and the control to this file will reached by travelling a long journey such as index.php, then Routes, filters and then the file I want to debug using break points.

**Second Part**

Second part of this question is that what are the best ways of debugging PHP Framework based application except 'var_dump()', 'print_r()', 'print()' etc.

Answer (score 0):

dd() function is similar to var_dump in laravel for debugging purpose. dd(mixed $variable) will dump the $variable and die.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question was about debugging, not to get the alternative of var_dump. Any help on debugging?

Comment: My question was to debug using BREAK POINTS not to find the alternative of var_dump(). Any help please?